# Associating Point Layer, Annotation Group and Line Layer in Map Legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, annotation

I have an annotation group containing charts associated with a point layer in an ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop layout. There are a number of line types on the charts.

How can I add the chart line symbology to the legend so it is displayed when the point layer is displayed?

Comment: @PolyGeo - I think you are a bit quick removing the python tag since (i) something needs to invoke a refresh, and (ii) I'd like to automate the whole thing in python.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works but my interpretation is that if there is no code then there should not be a Python or ArcPy tag on a question.

Comment: Fair comment. When I work out the code I'll include it and add the tag again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a group containing the point layer and an empty chart line layer,
- Add symbology to the empty chart line layer for each chart line,
- Associate the annotation layer with the charts to the main group.

When the group is displayed the points and chart annotation is displayed on the map and legend.

Unfortunately there appears to be a bug because unticking the group layer will not clear the chart annotation so a refresh is required to clear it. (Refresh probably best handled with python.)

Comment: Did you mean this as an answer to a non-coding question?  If it is just more information describing something that you want to automate then it should be an edit to your question, and your question should include a code attempt.