# Associating Inset Map with Layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, data-frame, scale-bar

I'd like to only display an inset map, inset map scale bar, frame and leader if an associated layer is displayed. Similar to [Associate Point Layer, Annotation Group and Line Layer in Map Legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309094/associate-point-layer-annotation-group-and-line-layer-in-map-legend) but for an inset map rather than annotation.

Any thoughts how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would use `arcpy.mapping` and code like this to move them off the page:

```
if lyr.visible == True:
    df.elementPositionX = 10 # wherever you want on the page
    df.elementPositionY = 10
    sclbr.elementPositionX = 5
    sclbr.elementPositionY = 5
else:
    df.elementPositionX = 100  # or anywhere off the page
    df.elementPositionY = 100
    sclbr.elementPositionX = 100
    sclbr.elementPositionY = 100
```

where `lyr` is the layer, `df` is the data frame of the inset map and `sclbr` is the scale bar element.

Comment: Layer is in a group so test lyr.longname I suppose

Comment: If you need help with getting a code snippet to work then please ask about that using a new question tagged ArcPy.

Comment: I don't think visible properties exist for dataframe or scalebar

Comment: They do in ArcGIS Pro which is what I usually work with nowadays.  As a workaround for ArcMap you could try using elementPositionX and elementPositionY to move them off and back on the page as needed.

Comment: Can this manage inset map frame and leader too?

Comment: Your "inset map frame" is just a DataFrame so, Yes.  The leader I'm not so sure about - it may still draw in from off the page.   If there were a visible property it would have handled it.  I recommend testing.

Comment: An alternative may be to not use the leader functionality and just use a graphic line for that instead.  Your code will need to draw it in the correct location so may not be trivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89320/discussion-between-nealei-and-polygeo).